# Python Selenium cant find the Add photos/videos button element on Facebook

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to upload an image to Facebook using selenium, but I am unable to click on the Add photos/videos ìmage button that looks like this:

[The button i want to click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsYHs.png)

```
<div aria-label="Photo/Video" class="oajrlxb2 gs1a9yip mtkw9kbi tlpljxtp qensuy8j ppp5ayq2 nhd2j8a9 mg4g778l pfnyh3mw p7hjln8o tgvbjcpo hpfvmrgz esuyzwwr f1sip0of n00je7tq arfg74bv qs9ysxi8 k77z8yql pq6dq46d btwxx1t3 abiwlrkh p8dawk7l lzcic4wl dwo3fsh8 g5ia77u1 goun2846 ccm00jje s44p3ltw mk2mc5f4 rt8b4zig n8ej3o3l agehan2d sk4xxmp2 rq0escxv kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x jb3vyjys rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso l9j0dhe7 i1ao9s8h du4w35lb" role="button" tabindex="0"><div><div><div class="tv7at329 l9j0dhe7 thwo4zme s45kfl79 emlxlaya bkmhp75w spb7xbtv"><div class="iyyx5f41 l9j0dhe7 cebpdrjk bipmatt0 k5wvi7nf a8s20v7p k77z8yql qs9ysxi8 arfg74bv n00je7tq a6sixzi8 tojvnm2t"><div class="bp9cbjyn j83agx80 taijpn5t l9j0dhe7 datstx6m k4urcfbm"><i data-visualcompletion="css-img" class="hu5pjgll bixrwtb6" style="height: 24px; width: 24px; background-image: url(&quot;https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yx/r/iMtJa5P8g3s.png&quot;); background-position: 0px -150px; background-size: auto; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline-block;"></i></div><div class="n00je7tq arfg74bv qs9ysxi8 k77z8yql i09qtzwb n7fi1qx3 b5wmifdl hzruof5a pmk7jnqg j9ispegn kr520xx4 c5ndavph art1omkt ot9fgl3s rnr61an3" data-visualcompletion="ignore"></div></div></div></div><div><div></div></div></div></div>
```

And this is the html

How do i fix this

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it in console?

Comment: post your code otherwise we cannot help

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to automate stuff if you don't use the API? So don't be surprised if your account get banned.